# Moon position differences on JPL Horizons, GMAT, Skyfield (using DE421)

Tags: the-moon, skyfield

I found a relevant difference in the positions for the Moon when calculating its Geocentric position with GMAT and Skyfield (https://rhodesmill.org/skyfield/), in both cases with JPL DE421. Additionally, I got the Moon position from JPL HORIZONS.

The euclidian distances between Skyfield/GMAT and Skyfiled/HORIZONS look as follows for 28 days (starting at JD TBD=2456021.501534172):
[image: euclidian distances between Skyfield/GMAT and Skyfiled/HORIZONS]

The average difference between Skyfield/HORIZONS is around 3 meters, whereas the Moon position output from GMAT shows a difference up to almost 60 meters. Looking at the distinct differences in x/y/z (all in ICRF):
[image]

Some screenshots from GMAT:

1. Ephemeris file
   [image]
2. Data output: asking for Moon position in geocentric ICRF
   [image]

I calculate the Moon position through Skyfield at the Julian Dates provided in the GMAT report file:

```
# preload Skyfield database / planets
planetsEphemeris = load('de421.bsp')
earth = planetsEphemeris['Earth']
moon = planetsEphemeris['Moon']
ts = load.timescale()

# load GMAT output
GMAToutput2 = '/Users/thibault/Desktop/GRAILA-Report.txt'
GMATcsv2 = pd.read_csv(GMAToutput2, sep='\s+', skiprows=0)  
GMATcsv2.loc[:,'JD_TBD'] = GMATcsv2.loc[:,'Luna.TDBModJulian'] + 2430000.0 # add JD-offset (ModJulian)

# add Skyfield Moon
MoonPos = moon.at(ts.tdb_jd(GMATcsv2.JD_TBD.values)).position.m - earth.at(ts.tdb_jd(GMATcsv2.JD_TBD.values)).position.m
GMATcsv2.loc[:,['MoonX','MoonY','MoonZ']] = MoonPos.T/1000

# differences
GMATcsv2.loc[:,['dX','dY','dZ']] = GMATcsv2.loc[:,['MoonX','MoonY','MoonZ']].to_numpy() - \
                                    GMATcsv2.loc[:,['Luna.EarthICRF.X','Luna.EarthICRF.Y', 'Luna.EarthICRF.Z']].to_numpy()
GMATcsv2.loc[:,['dXYZ']] = np.linalg.norm(GMATcsv2.loc[:,['dX','dY','dZ']] ,axis=1)[:,None]
```

For JPL HORIZONS, I simply used the state vector in ICRF, xy plane from reference frame, Geocentric position and Moon as target body. That's sufficient to get almost identical (~3 meters difference) results for Skyfield and HORIZONS.

Where could this difference come from?

- Is GMAT having its own definition of Earth-centered ICRF (aka GCRF)?
- Are there different ways to use DE ephemerides?
- Wrong settings in GMAT?

Any idea and input is appreciated!

Best,
Thibault

Comment: This checklist *may* be helpful: https://naif.jpl.nasa.gov/pub/naif/toolkit_docs/C/req/problems.html#Getting%20it%20Right